# How to make curve and rounded image in Blackberry 10 native?

Tags: image, image-processing, blackberry-10

I am trying to curve and round the image but I am not able to do it perfectly. I have tried to create an *.amd* file and set it as the background but this is not working perfectly.  Is there any other way through which I can make the image round as well as curved on a *Blackberry - 10.*?

I am getting an image as a response from the server like below:

[image]

I want something like the following images.Images are not static they are dynamic it's comes from web service.

[image]
[image]

I have checked the links from the BlackBerry forums also but did not get a proper solution. If anyone knows then please let me know.

Comment: The desired images you have provided don't describe to me what you want to achieve, and it isn't obvious either.  Also, I don't see how the fish image and the class image are related to each other.  What do you mean by "round"?

Comment: @rayryeng Those images are just an examples.I just want to make one image in to rounded image.

Comment: Please define what a "rounded" image is. I honestly have no idea.

Comment: @rayryeng "Rounded" menace the corner of the image should be 45 degree so it's look like a arc on a one corener. And for all corners i want the same curve.

Comment: Do you want a coded solution? What language?

Comment: yes and language is C++ ,QML,Blackberry 10 Native

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To put rounded corners on an image I would use the the Nine Slice feature described in the [API](https://developer.blackberry.com/native/documentation/cascades/best_practices/cascades_exporter/scaling_images.html). Using a drawing program crreate a small square example of the frame. Using the nine slice system to scale it to the size of your image and lay it over your image.

The same procedure will work for cicularly vignetting images. Depending on howmany sizes you want you may have to draw them on the fly or have several sizes and scale to other sizes.

Comment: sorry but the images are not static they are dynamic it's comes from web service.

Comment: @SmitPatel - Why don't you put all of the requirements in your post so that we're not second guessing ourselves and wasting time trying to suggest things that won't work?

Comment: @SmitPatel - dynamic images does not change things. Nine slicing frames allows them to adapt to the size and (rectangular) shape needed. And I did say you may need to scale or dynamically draw the circles. Do you have any vignetting code you've written for any platform?